# SQL/PHP query works in PHPmyAdmin but not the site

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

**SQL/PHP query works in PHPmyAdmin but not the site.**

I notice that many have had this problem but admittedly I am not as advanced as some of the coders on this site...yet. =) I humbly request any experience you may have laying around :P Thank you.

```
<?php
// session_start();
// ob_start();

ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(-1);

// Connection to database.
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('') or die(mysql_error());
?>

<?php
// Maintenance page.

$maintenance = 1; // 1 = Site Online || 0 = Site Offline 

if ($maintenance == 0) {
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    color:#ffffff;
                    background-color: #000000;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>  
    <center><img src="images/p4flogo.png" /></center><br /> 
    <?php
    echo "<br/><br /><center>This site is currently under maintenance.</center>";
} else {

// Start of main website.
    ?>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    color:#ffffff;
                    background-color: #000000;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                }    
                a:link {color: orange; text-decoration: underline; }
                a:active {color: red; text-decoration: underline; }
                a:visited {color: orange; text-decoration: underline; }
                a:hover {color: red; text-decoration: none; }
                table { 
                    border-color: #333333;
                }
                th { 
                    background-color:#ffffff;
                    color:#000000;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
                    height:30px;
                }
                td { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
                     color:#ffffff;
                     height:35px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="1" align="center">
            <tr><td>
            <center><img src="images/p4flogo.png" /></center><br /><br />
            <form action="" method="post">
                Search for a soldier: <input type="text" name="value" size="35" /><input type="submit" value="search" /><br />
                <?php
                if (isset($_POST['value']) && !empty($_POST['value'])) {
                    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
                    // query to database for soldier stats
                    // query works in phpmyadmin but not on site.
                         $sql = "
                               SELECT
                                `Name`,
                                 MAX(`Level`),
                                `Class`,
                                 SUM(`Kills`),
                                 SUM(`Deaths`),
                                 SUM(`Points`),
                                 SUM(`TotalTime`),
                                 SUM(`TotalVisits`),
                                 `CharacterID`
                               FROM
                                 `Characters`
                               WHERE
                                 `Name` LIKE '$value%' OR `CharacterID` LIKE '$value'
                               GROUP BY
                                 `Name`,
                                 `Class`,
                                 `CharacterID`
                               ORDER BY
                                 `Name` ASC;";
                    $query = mysql_query($sql);
                    $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if ($numrow >= 1) {
                        echo "<br /><a href=\"index.php\"><b>View TOP 100 Players!</b></a><br />";
                        echo "<table border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"5\">  ";
                        echo "<th>Soldier Name</th><th>Level</th><th>Class</th><th>KDR</th><th>Kills</th><th>Deaths</th><th>Points</th><th>Hours Played</th><th>Total Visits</th><th>CharacterID</th>";

                        echo "<br />";
                        WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

                            $SoldierName = $row['Name'];
                            $Level = $row['Level'];
                            $Class = $row['Class'];
                            if ($Class == NULL | empty($Class)) {
                                $Class = '<center>n / a</center>';
                            }
                            if ($Class == 1) {
                                $Class = 'Assault';
                            }
                            if ($Class == 2) {
                                $Class = 'Recon';
                            }
                            if ($Class == 3) {
                                $Class = 'Medic';
                            }
                            if ($Class == 4) {
                                $Class = 'Engineer';
                            }
                           echo $Kills = $row['Kills'];
                              if ($Kills == 0) {
                                  $Kills = 1;
                              }
                            $Deaths = $row['Deaths'];
                            if ($Deaths == 0) {
                                $Deaths = 1;
                            }
                            $Kdr = round($Kills / $Deaths, 2);
                            $Points = $row['Points'];

                            $TimePlayed = $row['TotalTime'];
                            if ($TimePlayed == 0) {
                                $TimePlayed = 1;
                            } else {
                                $TimePlayed = round(($TimePlayed / 3600), 0);
                            }

                            $TotalVisits = $row['TotalVisits'];
                            $CharacterID = $row['CharacterID'];

                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td><b>$SoldierName</b></td>";
                            echo "<td>$Level</td>";
                            echo "<td>$Class</td>";
                            if ($Kdr > 3.9) {
                                echo "<td><font color=\"red\"><b>$Kdr</b></font></td>";
                            } else if ($Kdr > 2.5 && $Kdr < 4) {
                                echo "<td><font color=\"orange\"><b>$Kdr</b></font></td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td><font color=\"limegreen\">$Kdr</font></td>";
                            }
                            echo "<td>$Kills</td>";
                            echo "<td>$Deaths</td>";
                            echo "<td>$Points</td>";
                            echo "<td>$TimePlayed</td>";
                            echo "<td>$TotalVisits</td>";
                            echo "<td>$CharacterID</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                    } else {
                        echo "No player found with that name. Please try again.";
                    }
                } else {
                    if (empty($_POST['value'])) {
                        echo "<font color=\"red\">You must enter a search value.</font>";
                    }
                    // query to p4f database for top 100 players.
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Characters` WHERE `Points` > 1 GROUP BY `Name` ORDER BY `Points` DESC LIMIT 100;";
                    $query = mysql_query($sql);
                    echo "<h3>TOP 100 PLAYERS</h3>";
                    echo "<table border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"5\">  ";
                    echo "<th></th><th>Soldier Name</th><th>Level</th><th>Class</th><th>KDR</th><th>Kills</th><th>Deaths</th><th>Points</th><th>Hours Played</th><th>Total Visits</th><th>CharacterID</th>";
                    // echo "Made it to loop!";
                    $Rank = 1;
                    WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

                        $SoldierName = $row['Name'];
                        $Level = $row['Level'];
                        $Class = $row['Class'];
                        if ($Class == NULL | empty($Class)) {
                                $Class = '<center>n / a</center>';
                            }
                        if ($Class == 1) {
                            $Class = 'Assault';
                        }
                        if ($Class == 2) {
                            $Class = 'Recon';
                        }
                        if ($Class == 3) {
                            $Class = 'Medic';
                        }
                        if ($Class == 4) {
                            $Class = 'Engineer';
                        }
                        $Kills = $row['Kills'];
                        if ($Kills == 0) {
                            $Kills = 1;
                        }
                        $Deaths = $row['Deaths'];
                        if ($Deaths == 0) {
                            $Deaths = 1;
                        }
                        $Kdr = round($Kills / $Deaths, 2);
                        $Points = $row['Points'];

                        $TimePlayed = $row['TotalTime'];
                        if ($TimePlayed == 0) {
                            $TimePlayed = 1;
                        } else {
                            $TimePlayed = round(($TimePlayed / 3600), 0);
                        }

                        $TotalVisits = $row['TotalVisits'];
                        $CharacterID = $row['CharacterID'];

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>$Rank</td>";
                        echo "<td><b>$SoldierName</b></td>";
                        echo "<td>$Level</td>";
                        echo "<td>$Class</td>";
                        if ($Kdr > 3.9) {
                            echo "<td><font color=\"red\"><b>$Kdr</b></font></td>";
                        } else if ($Kdr > 2.5 && $Kdr < 4) {
                            echo "<td><font color=\"orange\"><b>$Kdr</b></font></td>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<td><font color=\"limegreen\">$Kdr</font></td>";
                        }
                        echo "<td>$Kills</td>";
                        echo "<td>$Deaths</td>";
                        echo "<td>$Points</td>";
                        echo "<td>$TimePlayed</td>";
                        echo "<td>$TotalVisits</td>";
                        echo "<td>$CharacterID</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        $Rank++;
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                }
            }
            ?>
            </td></tr>             
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "works", and "doesn't". What error message, side effects, etc do you see? Kindly strip out the irrelevant code so we can focus on the real problems.

Comment: `WHERE Name LIKE Error()%` may be thats the problem? it doesnt make sense to me

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me either, but maybe Error() is part of the name, like Error()Bob.  I guess without more information we can't really figure it out.

Comment: No error messages. The values are 0 NULL empty or 1 shown on the soldier stats.

Comment: sorry ya Error() was a soldier.

Comment: `LIKE '$value'` is pointless without a wildcard - this is the equivalent of `='$value'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about MySQL, but I know that in SQL when you do an aggregate function, like SUM(`Kills`), then you can't reference the row via $row['kills'].  I don't know if this is your problem, but you could try doing SUM(`Kills`) as 'kills' in your SELECT statement.  Doing this for your aggregate SELECTs will allow you to reference them all this way.

Comment: that must be it. he needs to do `SUM(kills) as kills` etc and so on for every column to be able to do $row[kills]

Comment: I'll try this and post back in the next few minutes.